# Capturing parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

```
$url = '/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4';
$pattern = "\/article";

preg_match_all('/^'.$pattern.'(?:\/([^\/]+))+$/', $url, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => para4
        )
)
```

Actually, I want to get an array as given below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => math,
    [1] => unit2,
    [2] => chapter3,
    [3] => para4
)
```

What is wrong with this code?

UPDATE2: The $pattern is dynamic one. may change to "/article/foo", "/article/foo/bar", etc.

Comment: Sorry, $pattern is dynamic one. not $url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `explode()`

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
<?php
    $url = '/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4';

    $arr = explode("/", str_replace('/article/', '', $url));
    print_r($arr);

?>
```

Above code will output,

```
Array
(
    [0] => math
    [1] => unit2
    [2] => chapter3
    [3] => para4
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that for each match it overwrites the output for that match

In this case I believe that a simple explode will be more useful than a preg_match

Edit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$url = '/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4';
$args = explode('/', $url);
// since you don't want the first two outputs, heres some cleanup
array_splice($args, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use PHP Explode [Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php ]

```
$url = '/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4';
$data = explode("/", $url);
```

/ being the delimiter in your case

Answer (score 2):

Use **[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**

```
$url = '/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4';
$arrz = explode("/", $url);
print_r($arrz);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try using [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead?

```
$url = '/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4';
$matches = explode('/', $url);
$matches = array_slice($matches, 2); // drop the first 2 elements of the array - "" and "article"

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = '/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4';
$url=str_replace('/article/','','/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4');
print_r(explode('/','/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this cod as it is with the `,` you want in the output

```
<?php

$url = '/article/math/unit2/chapter3/para4';

$newurl = str_replace('/',',',$url);

$myarr = explode(',', $newurl);

$i = 0;
$c = count($myarr);

foreach ($myarr as $key => $val) {
    if ($i++ < $c - 1) {
        $myarr[$key] .= ',';
    }
}
$myarr = array_slice($myarr,2);
print_r($myarr);
```

**OUTPUT**--

```
Array
(
    [0] => math,
    [1] => unit2,
    [2] => chapter3,
    [3] => para4
)
```